# function running before call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

Can someone explain why the following code is displaying "library empty"? I'm not changing the input nor clicking on it, I don't understand why the function is being run.

```
import './App.css'; 
import {useState} from 'react'

function App() {
  const [library, setLibrary] = useState()

  const handleFile = () => {
    if (library) console.log('library full')
    console.log('library empty')
  }


  return (
    <form>
      <label>
        <div className='btn-three'>
          Select Directory:
          <input type="file" onClick={handleFile()}/>
        </div>
      </label>


    </form>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You're instantly calling the function when returning the JSX: `handleFile()`. You probably meant to use `handleFile`, without the parentheses.

Comment: Oh haha, didn't see that. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the function called

```
<input type="file" onClick={handleFile}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

In JSX function was directly called(**handleFile()**), instead of providing function reference(**handleFile**), so function got executed when browser loads scripts.

```
<input type="file" onClick={handleFile()}/>
```

Change above code to below

```
<input type="file" onClick={handleFile}/>
```